# Thickness of low frequency Mu shield calculation

Tags: electromagnetism, emc, magnetics, shielding

I am dealing with a low frequency varying magnetic field, say 10 - 100Hz with a magnitude of 0.8T. It seems shielding at this frequency gets tricky. Even though Mu is capable of doing it, there should be a thickness derivative formula with which I am struck.

How can I calculate the thickness to attenuate by a factor of 4? Is it possible? Also, inputs on eddy currents which will be generated in that shielding is appreciated.

Comment: Last time I did this I had to dig up some very old formulas that made assumptions about the geometry. You have to watch out for saturation. One of the mu-metal suppliers has an online calculator that borrows certain of the formulas but its best to go to the original papers (I think they were in German). It's also possible to do simulations but our budget wouldn't cover the required software.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - do you have these papers, a link to them or the title available?

Comment: Sorry it was a while ago and the info belongs to the client. I think it was in (or referenced in) **Review of Scientific Instruments** which should be accessible for free from any good library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These came from a textbook somewhere, but I can't remember the name of the book:

Absorbtion losses (in dB):
\begin{equation}
A = 20 \frac{t}{\delta} \log_{10}(e)
\end{equation}
t is the material thickness, e is the base of the natural logarithm, and \$\delta\$ is the skin depth.
\begin{equation}
\delta = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi \omega \mu \sigma}}
\end{equation}
\$\omega\$ is the frequency (in rad/s), \$\mu\$ is the magnetic permeability of the material, and \$\sigma\$ is the resistivity.

There are also reflective losses:
\begin{equation}
\|Z_s\| = \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi f \mu}{\sigma}}
\end{equation}
Then magnetic reflective losses (in dB) are:
\begin{equation}
R_m = 20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{\pi f \mu r}{2 \|Z_s\|}\right)
\end{equation}
Where r is the distance from the source to the shielding and f is the frequency in Hz.

I'm sure there's some assumptions made here, but I don't know what they are. Total attenuation is the sum of the two.

Comment: are you shure about "ω is the frequency (in rad/s)" that sounds like mechanical rotation? I would have expected something like "2&pi;f". I'm not familiar with magnetics but what has the distance of the source to do with the shielding capability?

Comment: Distance matters because it assumes near-field noise. I don't know if it should be \$\omega\$ in rad/s or f in Hz; see: http://www.learnemc.com/tutorials/Shielding01/Shielding_Theory.html (they have it as Hz)

Also, I found the book: H. Ott, Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering

Comment: Thank you for the link. I thought about EMP protection what i consider farfield :-) It seems that the paper covers both cases. In the document they only use pi*f and 2*pi*f and not omega, one hase to replace the upper omega with f and that is in Hz.

Comment: At 100 Hz, \$\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} = 477 km\$, so you are clearly in the near field unless you are thinking of a really far away EMP.

Comment: @helloworld922 - That was a informative link . Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I can speculate wildly about something I know very little about.
First I think @SpehroPefhany nailed it when he talked about saturation.  I think that will be your first concern.  The skin effect and such is less important for mu metal.. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal))

Now your magnet has more than just a field strength.  It also has a size (magnetic moment).  And it's the size that will determine how the B-field decreases with distance.  (It goes as one over the distance cubed... with the "characteristic" distance being something like the radius of the coil.. at least for simple coils.)  Now I think there is a trade off between the saturation field and the magnetic permeability.  So you can use a material with low saturation and high permeability, but you have to put it further away from your coil/magnet.  And of course that means more material.  You might consider shielding only the volume of your circuit or whatever that is sensitive to the field, rather than shielding the entire field.